# how to delete password field from user object in passport

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I need to create the session with user object via passport js, but in this part of a code, I can add only all user object, or user.id :

```
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
       done(null, **user.id or user**  );
       });
```

My object : 
   var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        email: String,
        password: String,
    },
    });

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
//Also i tried to delete object field here 
     //( delete user.local.password ) ,
           //but it didn't help
    done(null, user.id );
});
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` are for.

These two functions are the opposite of each other!

`serializeUser` you should put the `user.id` in the session, and `deserializeUser` is to get the whole user data. (e.g from the database for example).

See:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
    cb(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, cb) {
    // here you can find by Id, or do any query you want.
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      // here you can change to user object (removing the password), before pass it the cb function
      cb(err, user);  
    })
})
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: You really helped me) Now, I understand a difference between serializeUser and deserializeUser ) We can getting data with deserializeUser in req.user ) Data with serializeUser stored in req.session . We can added in req.session only user.id or all user object , it is true ?)Thank you so much ))